# Mongodb - set the sum of document properties into another after a successful update

Tags: mongodb

I have a **results** collection holding the scores of different teams. Each object here represents the score details of each team.

```
{
"_id" : "1",
"stats" : [
    {
    "memberId" : "player1",
    "stepNumber" : 1
    "timeToFinish" : 12
    },{
    "memberId" : "player1",
    "stepNumber" : 2
    "timeToFinish" : 18
    },{
    "memberId" : "player2",
    "stepNumber" : 1
    "timeToFinish" : 10
    },{
    "memberId" : "player2",
    "stepNumber" : 2
    "timeToFinish" : 12
    },
],
"totalTime" : 52 //12+18+10+12
}
```

Each time a member finishs a step, I update the **stats** array with the time spent to finish the step.
Because it's possible in my case to change this time after adding it (in case of correction for example), I delete the current entry (if it exists) having the same **memberId** and **stepNumber** before inserting the new one.

This works fine.

Now I want to maintain the **totalTime** property to always hold the Sum of all the **timeToFinish** properties of the object.
I need this because I need to show the top N total times and it's better from a performance perspective (there are up to 10k documents) to have the total calculated instead of calculating it each time I do a top N request.

Is there a way to process this property after each successful update of thee document?

**NB:** I use Mongodb 3.6

Answer (score -1):

You can use $push to update the array stats and $inc to update the totalTime at the same time.

Comment: This would be possible solution if this use case doesn't exists (from the original post) **Because it's possible in my case to change this time after adding it (in case of correction for example), I delete the current entry (if it exists) having the same memberId and stepNumber before inserting the new one.**

Comment: It sounds like some trigger mechanism of  CRUD. If you want just that trigger, I have not met it. Good luck.